# How do i make my page blank with a query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I set the URL to exmaple.com?blank=true a blank page should be presented.

Using JavaScript or jQuery i want a short snippet that looks for ?blank=true in the url and if it finds it than the page to turn white or blank.

Comment: i know how to do it..... watch my answer

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/2dyc3k6j/

Comment: watch out answer that i given below.... will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your html content in a element like this

```
<html>
  <body>
     <div id="wrapper">
          <!-- ********your content here******** -->
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

use jquery code as

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('=');
        if(sURLVariables[0]=="blank" && sURLVariables[1]=="true") 
           {$('#wrapper').css('display','none');}
        else{
            $('#wrapper').css('display','block');           
            }
    });
```

Comment: remove this code ----------------  " $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', 'body', function(){$(document).on('load', '.bob-square', function(){var status = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';alert(status);if(status==="online") {$("#check-connection > span").css("", "");} else if(status==="offline") {$(".bob-square > span").css("display", "none");}});});
        "

Comment: and also keep script out of <main> tag

Comment: i removed the code and also moved your code out of the tag and it still isn't working

Comment: how do i fix this?

Comment: add <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script> in head tag

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```js
var url_string = "https://example.com?blank=true "; //window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var blank = url.searchParams.get("blank");

if(blank){
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.display = "none";


}
```

```html
<body>

<p>this will be hidden</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery

```
var blank = /(?<=blank=)[^&?]+/g.exec('https://example.com?blank=true')[0];
if(blank === 'true'){
    $('body').hide();
}else{
    $('body').show();
}
```